# php script for uploading a file is not working as per expected

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**I have written a php code for uploading a file,but it seems there is
   some issue with the code.can anyone plz help me out in resolving the
   issue.**
The HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
 copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "C:/xampp/htdocs" ) or 
       die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else
{
  die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'] ; ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size']/1024;  ?> 
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
<?php $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**I am using xampp to run the PHP scripts.**

**Onclicking

> upload file
>    button nothing is displayed as expected.**

Comment: You are supposed to use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`

Comment: i changed to move_uploaded_file() but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

So what is the output? Also, do `print_r($_FILES)` to show how it is prepared for you to access, you are likely to be accessing the filename inaccurately.

Comment: I already told that by writing the code line above, you would be able to see the structure of $_FILES array. And as ThiefMaster already mentioned, you need to write it like that. You aren't even trying to fix it even tho we both already answered your question :( That is disappointing. No wonder you got so many negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper function and the correct array element:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '...');
```